# Char to Ascii conversion spitting out a variable-sized object error

Tags: c, printf, return-value, declaration, function-definition

I have a function that makes determines string length and all the variables used are defined globally but when i try and compile the code it spits out the error

`variable-sized object may not be initialized`

I want the function to take every character in an array and convert it into its ascii value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


//defining global variables
char variable[100];
char alphabet[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
int shift;
int stringlength;
int i;


//function that inputs a piece of string and writes it to the global variable
char input(){
        printf("Type your string: ");
        fgets(variable, 100, stdin);
        stringlength = strlen(variable) - 1;
}


//function that checks an input for string and checks its between 0 and 25
int inputandtest(){
        int shift;
        printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 26: ");
        scanf("%d", &shift);
        shift --;
        //check for whether or not the inputted shift number is a valid number (within 0-25 for the alphabet)
        while (shift < 0 || shift > 25){
                printf("That number is invalid please enter a new one: ");
                scanf("%d", &shift);
                shift--;
                }
        return shift;

}

//hopefully something that'll turn a sentence into an ascii thing
int conversion(int stringlength){
        for (i = 0; i < stringlength; i++)
        {
                int ascii[i] = variable[i];
                printf(ascii[i]);
        }

}

//main stuff
int main(){
        input();
        int shiftA;
        shiftA = inputandtest();
        printf("Alphabet letter %c\n", alphabet[shiftA]);
        printf("%d\n", stringlength);
        int ascii[stringlength];
        conversion(stringlength);
}
```

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [mre].

Comment: `int ascii[i] = variable[i];` This line is clearly wrong as it is declaring a new array and trying to assign a single value to it. Perhaps you meant that to be `ascii[i] = variable[i];` But the code is too incomplete to be sure and to be able to give a fuller answer.

Comment: The function `strlen` returns the length of the string NOT including the terminating null character. Therefore, the line `stringlength = strlen(variable) - 1;` is probably wrong.

Comment: `int ascii[i] = variable[i]; printf(ascii[i]);` That code really doesn't make much sense. In addition to the problem identified in my previous comment the first arg to `printf` needs to be a `char *` not an `int`. Remove those lines and try just `printf("%d", variable[i]);` if you want the ascii int value.

Comment: how would i go about storing those outputs kaylum? im very new to C.

Comment: If you want to store it in a seperate array then you need to declare one *outside* the loop. Like : `int ascii[stringlength]; for (i = 0; i < stringlength; i++) { ascii[i] = variable[i]; }`.

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
//hopefully something that'll turn a sentence into an ascii thing
int conversion(int stringlength){
        for (i = 0; i < stringlength; i++)
        {
                int ascii[i] = variable[i];
                printf(ascii[i]);
        }

}
```

is incorrect.

Firstly you are declared a variable length array that may not be initislaized

```
int ascii[i] = variable[i];
```

It seems you mean

```
ascii[i] = variable[i];
```

But in this case you need to pass to the function the declared array in main

```
int ascii[stringlength];
```

Secondly this call of printf

```
printf(ascii[i]);
```

is also incorrect. You need to write at least

```
printf( "%d", ascii[i] );
```

Also the function has the return type `int` but returns nothing.

And within this function

```
//function that inputs a piece of string and writes it to the global variable
char input(){
        printf("Type your string: ");
        fgets(variable, 100, stdin);
        stringlength = strlen(variable) - 1;
}
```

this statement

```
stringlength = strlen(variable) - 1;
```

can store an incorrect value of the string length if the user will enter for example a string with more than 99 characters. That is it is not necessary that the new line character `'\n'` will be present in the string.

And the function returns nothing though its return type is `char`.

You need to write

```
//function that inputs a piece of string and writes it to the global variable
void input(){
        printf("Type your string: ");
        fgets(variable, sizeof( variable ), stdin);
        variable[ strcspn( variable, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
        stringlength = strlen(variable);
}
```

And the variable `stringlength` should be declared as having the type `size_t`.

```
size_t stringlength;
```